# Unable to determine event type for AWS Lambda serverless function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a very simple handler that I'm using to familiarize myself with serverless lambda functions.

```js
const example: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async event => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Success',
    }),
  };
};
```

Here is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: lambda-example
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  example:
    handler: lib/handler.example
    events:
      - http:
          path: example
          method: get
          integration: lambda
```

When I hit the API it works just fine...

```json
{
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "{"message":"Success"}"
}
```

I'm using this URL to trigger the event `http://localhost:3000/dev/example?url=https://google.com/` and I'm console logging the event itself when the endpoint is hit...

```json
{
  "body": {},
  "method": "GET",
  "principalId": "offlineContext_authorizer_principalId",
  "stage": "dev",
  "cognitoPoolClaims": {
    "sub": ""
  },
  "enhancedAuthContext": {
    "principalId": "offlineContext_authorizer_principalId"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Host": "localhost:3000",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"
  },
  "query": {
    "url": "https://google.com/"
  },
  "path": {},
  "identity": {
    "accountId": "offlineContext_accountId",
    "apiKey": "offlineContext_apiKey",
    "apiKeyId": "offlineContext_apiKeyId",
    "caller": "offlineContext_caller",
    "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognitoAuthenticationType": "offlineContext_cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "sourceIp": "127.0.0.1",
    "user": "offlineContext_user",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    "userArn": "offlineContext_userArn"
  },
  "stageVariables": {},
  "requestPath": "/example"
}
```

I'm interested in accessing the 'query' attribute of this object but TypeScript gets mad at me when I try...

```
console.log(event.query);

===

Property 'query' does not exist on type 'APIGatewayProxyEvent'.
```

The query attribute very clearly exists on the event object as shown in my console log so I'm assuming I'm incorrectly typing this function, but I can't seem to find the proper type. What am I doing wrong here?

Additional Info (package.json):

```json
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.21.0",
  "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.64",
  "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.22",
  "@types/node": "^14.14.2",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
  "eslint": "^7.12.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
  "husky": "^4.3.0",
  "prettier": "^2.1.2",
  "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
  "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^3.1.0",
  "serverless-offline": "^6.8.0",
  "typescript": "^4.0.3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was the

```
integration: lambda
```

addition to my serverless.yml file. When I removed this line the `APIGatewayProxyHandler` interface worked as expected.